# Getting error for function call in test cases

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a class which has all the constants used in the application

```
export class Constants {
    static getDefault(): any {
        return {
                url_path : '/API Path',
                etc
            } 
        }
    }
```

which I am consuming in service I have imported this class and using import ConstantVal = app.base.Constants;  and used in  url = 'https://'  + ConstantVal.getDefault().urlpath ;

In my Service spec.ts I am getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDefault' of undefined for the function

How to add this dependency for my test cases?
Spec code:

```
Spec Code:

/// <reference path='../../../../../typings/_references.ts' />

module app.base.apis {
   import ConstantVal = ptsp.base.Constants;
     describe('Service API calls tests ', function ():any {
 var apiService:any;
  var $httpBackend:any;
  //var constants:ptsp.base.Constants;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('App'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('App.core'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(
     function ($injector:ng.auto.IInjectorService):any {
        apiService = $injector.get('apiService');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    }));

  it('It should call the DELETE API', function ():any {
     const constants = new Constants;
     ConstantVal.getDefault();  
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

getDefault is defined as static method. So you need to use the full name of class in order to call this method.

```
Constants.getDefault();
```

Another thing, you should mark your method as public method:

```
   export class Constants {
        public static getDefault(): any {
            return {
                    url_path : '/API Path',
                    etc
                } 
            }
        }
```

Spec Code:

```
/// <reference path='../../../../../typings/_references.ts' />

module app.base.apis {

'use strict';

import ConstantVal = ptsp.base.Constants;

declare var readJSON:any;

describe('Service API calls tests ', function ():any {

  var apiService:any;
  var $httpBackend:any;
  //var constants:ptsp.base.Constants;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('App'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('App.core'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(
     function ($injector:ng.auto.IInjectorService):any {
        apiService = $injector.get('apiService');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    }));

  it('It should call the DELETE API', function ():any {
     const constants = new Constants;
     ConstantVal.getDefault();  
});
}
```